Converge uniformly on compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$
Let $\scr{F}$ be the family of functions that are holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(\mathbb{D})\subset \mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$. If $f_n$ is a sequence in $\scr{F}$ such that $f_n(0)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ prove $f_n(z)\to 0$ uniformly on compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.
If we post compose $\dfrac{i-z}{i+z}\circ i\sqrt{z} \circ f_n(z)$ and denote it $F_n$ then we have $F_n: \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$. And we see that the family $\{F_n\}$ is precompact because it is in  $\mathbb{D} $ for all $n$ so it is compactly bounded. So there exists a subsequence $F_{n_k}$ converge in $\mathbb{D}$ compactly. But I dont know if this is the right direction and wasnt able to get to anywhere. Could someone provide some help? Thanks

What is the reason you doubt this argument and why were you "unable to get anywhere?"

your argument is on the right track - the only thing to note (and this is where maybe the confusion lies) is that under a biholomorphism from $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ onto $\mathbb D$ the number $0$ from $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ goes to a unit circle point $w$ (eg $1$ in your choice), so the corresponding $F_n:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ satisfy $F_n(0) \to w, n \to \infty$ eg $F_n(0) \to 1$ for your choice; now can you conclude?

@Conrad Thanks! I see that $F_n\to  1$ at 0 but I dont see how that will help me conclude that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on compact set.  I'm thinking I need to find an integer $N>0$ such that for all compact set $K\subset \mathbb{D}$ and $f(p)$ epsilon close to $0$ for all $p\in K$. I was thinking pick $N$ large enough such that $F_n(0)$ is close to $1$ for all $n\geq N$. But then I dont know how to relate this back to $f_n(z)$.

Show that $F_n \to 1$ at $0$ implies that $F_n \to 1$ locally uniformly on the whole unit disc (any limit function of $F_n$ will attain its maximum modulus at $0$ hence will be constant...) and then going back to $f_n$ gives the result

@Conrad Oh I see, because limit of $F_n$ is a holomorphic function from $\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ and then apply maximum principal so Limit is a constant function on $\mathbb{D}$.

correct - this proves it
